# Using the same variable to compute the zero-point energy difference of Casimir Effect

Tags: casimir-effect

I am reading the original work of Casimir: *On the attraction between two perfectly conducting plates (1948)*

[image]

In general, the zero-point energy is

$$U_0 =\frac12  \hbar c \sum_{k_x=0}^{\infty} \sum_{k_y=0}^{\infty} \sum_{k_z=0}^{\infty} \sqrt{k_x^2 + k_y^2 + k_z^2} \, g(\omega_k)$$

where $g$ is the degeneracy of the mode.

The zero-point energy $E_0$ when the plates are separated by some distance $a$ is calculated by going to the continuum in the plane $k_x \, k_y$ as $L\to\infty$ and taking into account that $g = 1$ for modes with $k_z = 0$

$$E_0 = \frac12 \sum_{\vec{k}}\hbar \omega_k = \hbar c \frac{L^2}{\pi^2} \frac{\pi}{2} \int_{0}^{\infty} \rho \, d\rho \left\{ \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \sqrt{\rho^2 + \left( \frac{\pi n}{a} \right)^2} + \frac{\rho}{2}  \right\} $$

The next step is to find the zero point energy $E_0'$ when $a\to\infty$. Now, we also go to the continuum in $k_z$ as $a$ is comparable to $L$. It is easy to show that

$$E_0' = \hbar c \frac{L^2}{\pi^2} \frac{\pi}{2} \frac{a}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} \rho \, d\rho dk_z  \sqrt{\rho^2 +k_z^2}$$

The zero-point energy diference is just $\delta E = E_0 - E_0'$

---

My question is... is it right to use the same variable '$a$' for both configurations? We could write $\delta E(a) = E_0(a) - E_0(a\to\infty)$ In that case, doesn't it only hold for large enough values of '$a$'?

For the next steps, he mixes the '$a$' from the first configuration (which is finite) with the '$a$' from the second configuration (which is "infinite")